# Вычитание времени

Tags: php, дата

Есть три времени, получаемые из БД (Время прихода, время ухода и перерывы).
Пробую делать так:

```
    $time1 = strtotime($row['3']); // Время выключения
    $time2 = strtotime($row['2']); //Время включения
    $time3 = strtotime($row['4']); //Перерывы
    $diff = $time1-$time2-$time3;
    $summi = floor($diff);
```

Считает не совсем правильно. К примеру:

Время включения: 04:47:00

Время выключения: 05:33:00

Перерывы: 00:07:33

Должно получиться 00:38:27 а получается 20:38:27

Что не так?

Comment: Перерывы - это сумма всех перерывов же?) Вам надо перевести их в секунды и просто отнять не как `strtotime` а как просто секунды от общего значения времени)

Comment: Оказалось все чуть проще, ставил установку временной зоны GMT-10, убрал, теперь вместо 20:38:27 пишет 05:38:27

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что корректно высчитанной разнице должны быть побоку часовые пояса? Час он ведь и в Африке час.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `DateInterval` для корректного вычисления разницы.
Если я правильно понял, `$row[4]` содержит суммарное количество секунд на перерывы.

```
$row = [
  '2' => '2017-02-06 08:00:00',
  '3' => '2017-02-06 18:10:00',
  '4' => 3660
];

$dateOn  = new \DateTime($row['2']);
$dateOff = new \DateTime($row['3']);
$delays = (int)$row['4'];
$dateOn->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$delays.'S'));

$time = $dateOff->diff($dateOn);
echo $time->format('%H:%I:%S'); // 09:09:00
```

---

```
$row = [
  '2' => '06:25:00',
  '3' => '07:00:00',
  '4' => '00:10:00'
];

$dateOn  = new \DateTime($row['2']);
$dateOff = new \DateTime($row['3']);

if ($dateOn > $dateOff) {
  $dateOff->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day'));
}    

if ($row['4']) {
  list($h, $i, $s) = explode(':', $row[4]);
  $dateOn->add(new DateInterval("PT{$h}H{$i}M{$s}S"));
}
$time = $dateOff->diff($dateOn);
echo $time->format('%H:%I:%S'); // 00:25:00
```

Этот формат очень неудачен:

1. Интервал хранится, как отформатированное время, проще хранить его просто, как число секунд.
2. Отсутствуют даты, там, где они необходимы. Приходится вручную проверять факт смены дат. Если кто-либо захочет поработать более суток, результат будет некорректен.

Comment: Если делать данным способом, то выдает ошибку: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' "

Comment: Первая строка - всего лишь инициализация, у вас должен быть другой источник для `$row`.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, моя ошибка, все понял. Теперь же ругается на "Unknown or bad format (PTS)'"

Comment: Что у вас в `$row['4']`? Судя по всему пусто. Должно быть некоторое количество секунд

Comment: Запрос выбирает все записи о конкретном сотруднике. $row['4'] - общее количество перерывов, то есть их может не быть вообще. С нулевым временем не получиться таким образом, я так полагаю?

Comment: Я уже обновил ответ для возможного значения NULL. Что значит не получится? Неразрешимых задач очень немного.

Comment: Заработало, но считает не верно. Вместо 31:18, пишет 35:00; вместо 38:27 выдает 46:00

Comment: Дайте ваши исходные данные.

Comment: выдало вот это bool(false)

Comment: По традиции напоминаю, что `mysql_* api` **жутко устарел**, найдите время для перехода на pdo/mysqli

Comment: array(10) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-02-03" ["date"]=> string(10) "2017-02-03" [1]=> string(15) "g431k-monsterpc" ["pcid"]=> string(15) "g431k-monsterpc" [2]=> string(8) "06:25:00" ["timeon"]=> string(8) "06:25:00" [3]=> string(8) "07:00:00" ["timeoff"]=> string(8) "07:00:00" [4]=> string(8) "00:03:42" ["timeout"]=> string(8) "00:03:42" }

Comment: Время перерыва считывается таймером, и знать когда перерыв начался и закончился не нужно, поэтому и дата

Comment: Неважно, количество секунд - это не дата. Дата - некорректный тип для хранения интервала. В любом случае, я адаптировал решение под ваш формат. Он кстати, будет страдать, если кто-либо захочет поработать ночью.